# myslq workbench 8.0 query editor will not process UPDATE or INSERT

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Just starting with workbench and can not get UPDATE or INSERT to function I get a 'Query interrupted' comment. My test script is very simple on a Db table with 4 rows:

```
INSERT INTO `school`.`students` (StudentId, FirstName, LastName, Class, Age) 
VALUES (1, 'Hina', 'Sharma', 'First', 18);
```

I can enter the data manually, but not through the editor. I have turned OFF 'safe updates' and have DBA Privileges. All SELECT queries run as expected.
I have the same issue on another test Db's. One created through the import wizard and this one was created manually.
SQL server is running on localhost and Ubuntu 22.04
Thanks for the help

Comment: SQL server?? That's confusing mysqlworkbench is normally used to connect to MYSQL server

Comment: Sorry, I am Using MySQL server